# Create terminal for ssh on socket with Python

Tags: python, sockets, ssh, subprocess

I need to create a terminal/console program on my server compute and I want to connect to it with ssh from client. And I want to do it from a python script. So, I figured that I need to somehow have this script run the program (`subprocess` maybe?) and put it out on the socket.

How can I put out a certain program on a specified socket for ssh connection?

Can I even ssh to a certain program run in a console, not to a whole PC? I need client to have only acces to what I set up.

Comment: Whats your question? What have you tried? Help the group, help you!

Comment: I specified it a bit. I haven't tried anything as I didn't find anything similar, or just don't know how to look for it :/

Comment: look at paramiko.  it has demos for both client and server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How can I put out a certain program on a specified socket for ssh connection?

I think that what you actually want to do is changing what is run when logging in with ssh.

You can do this in /etc/passwd by changing /bin/bash to the program you want to run when you log in. Do this for the user that you want to log in to via ssh.

I didn't understand if you wanted to log in from a python script or log in to a python program in an interactive shell, so:

You can use the paramiko library to log into a machine with ssh. (if that is what you want)

> I need to create a terminal/console program on my server compute and I want to connect to it with ssh from client.

You can look at this project https://github.com/python-cmd2/cmd2 to build interactive console programs in python.

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into the link!